# How to limit cookies of a domain only to that specific domain?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, cookies

I'm using the new Edge browser, I have added only a couple of websites' cookies to be kept after browser closes and the rest are deleted.
YouTube.com and Google.com cookies are among the ones that I set to be kept, just because I use YouTube.
but I notice that when I visit other websites such as Reddit or Pinterest, I am offered to sign into my Google account in order to make an account on those sites.

I don't want this to happen, I don't want other websites to be able to have anything to do with cookies of other domains. how can I restrict Google.com's cookies only to Google.com and YouTube.com's cookies only to YouTube.com ?

p.s I don't want to block 3rd party cookies altogether, not sure if it even would work.

Comment: keep in mind, that a modern webpage consists of contents from dozens of domains, and yes scripts linked from a google.com domain will be able to see cookies for google.com that are not marked as http-only. Cookie storage and access already work as you describe, but because the content came from google.com it will have access, even though that content is embedded in another domains site (xyz.com).

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks, what if I blocked 3rd party cookies? would that prevent it? since I think cookies coming from Google.com are considered 3rd party when visiting Reddit.com

Comment: @FrankThomas 2nd question, would it be possible for Edge developers to add 3rd party cookie blocking feature for individual domains? or restrict them only to their original domain? I'm thinking about suggesting this feature but want to make sure if it's technically possible first.

Comment: yes, that is the definition of a 3rd party cookie. https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/what-are-third-party-cookies/ it is theoretically possible to filter 3rd party cookies, but the task is daunting, so mostly its controlled by browser extensions that provide some greater intelligence in selecting the cookies to be blocked. examples include (for firefox): Privacy Badger (EFF),  Cookie AutoDelete, DuckduckGo extension, etc.

Comment: @FrankThomas I found out the solution, it's been in Edge all the time but I failed to notice it. posted it as an answer here. tested it and works exactly the way i want.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is already available in Edge browser and I overlooked it

in Edge settings: edge://settings/content/cookies

You need to block all 3rd party cookies

[image]

and then add the sites whose 3rd party cookies you want to be allowed, to the "Allow" list and make sure to check the box that says "include 3rd party cookies for this site"

[image]

[image]

That's it. works like a charm. blocks 3rd party cookies on all websites except those specified in this list.